# Failed to get return value map on method in elixir

Tags: elixir

I am using an elixir library `Rox` to manage data in rocksdb. There is a delete method defined as below:

```
delete(db_or_cf, key, write_opts \\ [])
delete(Rox.DB.t | Rox.ColumnFamily.t, key, write_options) ::
  :ok |
  {:error, any}
```

I am using below way to call this method:

```
result = case Rox.delete(db, :erlang.term_to_binary(key)) do
            {:ok} -> {:ok}
            {:error} -> {:error}
        end
```

But I got an error: `(CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: :ok`. 
I am new to elixir and I don't know why the :ok doesn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{:ok}` is not `:ok`. First expression is one element tuple, second is simply an atom.

Try this:

```
result = case Rox.delete(db, :erlang.term_to_binary(key)) do
  :ok -> :ok
  {:error, _any} -> {:error, _any}
end
```

Comment: why don't you just do `result = Rox.delete(db, :erlang.term_to_binary(key))`, since case is useless here

Answer (score 1):

The function returns either `:ok` or `{:error, any()}` so the patterns you need to match are `:ok` and `{:error, error}`. You have an extra `{}` around `:ok` and `:error` tuple should have a second element.

```
case Rox.delete(db, :erlang.term_to_binary(key)) do
  :ok -> ...
  {:error, error} -> ...
end
```